# Python pathlib make directories if they don’t exist

Tags: python, pathlib

If I wanted to specify a path to save files to and make directories that don’t exist in that path, is it possible to do this using the pathlib library in one line of code?

Answer (score 358, accepted):

Yes, that is [`Path.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir):

```
pathlib.Path('/tmp/sub1/sub2').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir):

> If *parents* is true, any missing parents of this path are created as
> needed; they are created with the default permissions without taking
> *mode* into account (mimicking the POSIX `mkdir -p` command).
>
> If *parents* is false (the default), a missing parent raises
> `FileNotFoundError`.
>
> If *exist_ok* is false (the default), `FileExistsError` is raised if the
> target directory already exists.
>
> If *exist_ok* is true, `FileExistsError` exceptions will be ignored (same
> behavior as the POSIX `mkdir -p` command), but only if the last path
> component is not an existing non-directory file.

Comment: with `exist_ok` set to `true`, does mkdir just overwrite the dir and make it again? Or does it skip (re)making the dir since it already exists?

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally the latter—calling `mypath.mkdir(exist_ok=True)` will not raise an error, and will leave the existing directory associated with `mypath` intact.

Answer (score 17):

Adding to Wim's answer. If your path has a file on the end that you do not want made as a directory.

ie.
'/existing_dir/not_existing_dir/another_dir/a_file'

Then you use PurePath.parents. But the nice thing is that because Paths inherit the attributes of Pure Paths, then you can simply do

```
filepath = '/existing_dir/not_existing_dir/another_dir/a_file'
pathlib.Path(filepath).parents[0].mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Nice! This is the neatest example and work well.

Comment: or even shorter Path(filepath).parent

Comment: For the copy cats here `pathlib.Path(path).parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)`

Answer (score 13):

This gives additional control for the case that the path is already there:

```py
path = Path.cwd() / 'new' / 'hi' / 'there'
try:
    path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=False)
except FileExistsError:
    print("Folder is already there")
else:
    print("Folder was created")
```

Answer (score -1):

Universal function to create dirs/files that do not exist

```
def check_and_create_path(self, path: Path):
        path_way = path.parent if path.is_file() else path

        path_way.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

        if not path.exists():
            path.touch()
```