# Trying to make a folder using pathlib

Tags: pathlib

Title: How to make a folder with pathlib.

Content: Im trying to make a folder with pathlib. if i do this:

```
exercises_dir = Path('projects')
folder2 = exercises_dir / "exercise2"
folder2.mkdir()
```

it makes the folder but if i instead do this:

```
folder = exercises_dir / "exercise2" / "john"
```

I get a winerror3 the system cannot find the path specified.
I dont get what I am doing wrong here. Can i just make one folder at a time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pathlib make directories if they don’t exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110800/python-pathlib-make-directories-if-they-don-t-exist)